# How to keep the code consistent between debug and release version with LeakCanary

Tags: android, leakcanary

When I use LeakCanary with version 2.4, it delete the leakcanary-android-no-op artifact.
But in the code, to avoid some leak report. I use the code like this:

```
LeakCanary.config = LeakCanary.config.copy(
  referenceMatchers = AndroidReferenceMatchers.appDefaults +
      AndroidReferenceMatchers.ignoredInstanceField(
          className = "com.temp.view.DeleteableEditText",
              fieldName = "mContext"
      )
)
```

And it also import something`import leakcanary.LeakCanary`, `import shark.AndroidReferenceMatchers`. So it will compile errors in release code.

If I want to compile release code, I should delete my code above. I want to know if any way to help me keep the same code between debug and release version

By the way, I try to use `Implementation "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.4"`, but as the tips from LeakCanary

> We do not recommend including LeakCanary in release builds, as it could negatively impact the experience of your customers. To avoid accidentally including the com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android dependency in a release build, LeakCanary crashes during initialization if the APK is not debuggable.

So I don't want to **running** LeakCanary in release builds.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a [debug variant](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types), add debug sources and create a debug application class that configures LeakCanary.

Comment: can you show me a demo how to build a debug class which will not run in release version, thanks